# Moment TZ - Convert date into another timezone ISO string

Tags: javascript, timezone, momentjs, moment-timezone

I'm trying to convert a date in GMT to PST. The GMT date is `2022-11-16T00:00:00`, therefore the PST date should be `2022-11-15T16:00:00`.

My code is as follows:

```
const startDateGMT = moment(startTime).tz(myTimezone, true);
console.log('START DATE GMT IS', startDateGMT, startDateGMT.toISOString());
```

This outputs 8AM on the 16th, instead of 4PM on the 15th:

```
START DATE GMT IS Moment<2022-11-16T00:00:00-08:00> 2022-11-16T08:00:00.000Z
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`moment.tz`](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/parsing-in-zone/) constructor to parse the input time, using the timezone `Etc/GMT` as the timezone.

You can then call [`.tz()`](https://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/#/using-timezones/converting-to-zone/) on the resulting date to convert to Pacific time.

The example below creates the dates and formats them along with the relevant UTC offset.

```js
const gmtTime = '2022-11-16T00:00:00';

const gmtDate = moment.tz(gmtTime, 'Etc/GMT');
const pstDate = moment.tz(gmtTime, 'Etc/GMT').tz('US/Pacific');

console.log('GMT Date:', gmtDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ssZ'))
console.log('PST Date:', pstDate.format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ssZ'))
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment-timezone-with-data.js"></script>
```